# pjax with rails 3.1 redirect_pjax_to renders only text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pjax

I try to use pjax-rails gem for the a project.

When I use the redirect method from the gem. The browser renders the response as text.
I asume text/javascript instead of script/javascript.

This is how my controller looks (notice redirect_to_pjax):

```
 def create
@contact = Contact.new params[:contact]
if @contact.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully added contact"
    redirect_pjax_to :show,@contact
end
```

this is the gem https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails

This is the original implementation of the method "redirect_pjax_to"
I think the magic happens here.... (taken from github)

```
 private  
def redirect_pjax_to(action, url = nil)
  new_url = url_for(url ? url : { action: action })

  render js: <<-EJS
    if (!window.history || !window.history.pushState) {
      window.location.href = '#{new_url}';
    } else {
      $('[data-pjax-container]').html(#{render_to_string("#{action}.html.erb", layout: false).to_json});
      $(document).trigger('end.pjax');

      var title = $.trim($('[data-pjax-container]').find('title').remove().text());
      if (title) document.title = title;
      window.history.pushState({}, document.title, '#{new_url}');
    }
  EJS
end
```

I asume that render :js needs a content_type here...

Does anyone has the same problems? Or better any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see whether you made an AJAX call? If you create from an input element, instead of anchor element, I think pjax will not get triggered

I use PJAX in my Rails application by just checking the header of the HTTP request for PJAX and then do render :layout false. Works like a charm.

Comment: I can work with links without a problem. It is when I use the redirect_pjax_to method in the controller which comes with the pjax-rails gem. This method is the eq. for redirect_to just with ajax/pjax.